# Published an instant app: can't make it to start, how do I troubleshoot?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I've just published my first instant app - for now it's a very basic Hello World, but I've linked it to my personal website.

I've enabled Android App Links on my site, and I've verified that it correctly works: when the 'normal' apk is installed, if I click on my website's link, it does open the app, without asking if I want to open it in Chrome.

But when the apk is not installed, if I click on my website's link, the Instant App doesn't start - instead my website opens in Chrome (or a Chrome tab) and I don't know why.

How do I troubleshoot this?

**Note:**
I did receive this *warning* on the Play Store console when I published:

```
PROBLEM
Some users of this Instant App APKs will not be eligible for any of the APKs in your installed app.

RESOLUTION
Ensure that the targeting of your Instant App APKs matches the targeting of your APKs.
```

I don't know if it's related, and unfortunately I have no idea what that means or how to fix it...

---

**EDIT 2017-07-01**

Actually it started to work after a few days.  I guess it means even though the installable app is available on the store after only a few minutes, the instant app is available several days after publishing...

Unfortunately,

1. I have a new problem now (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858798/instant-app-wont-start-directly-shows-a-screen-first))
2. I still don't have an answer for my original question which is how to troubleshoot these problems
3. Still no idea about the warning - although I guess it's an unrelated issue

Comment: We got he same warning, also with an error message, currently we are only successfully uploaded Instant App but unable to "rollout" Instant App to production. Do you have the solution ?

Comment: @BoD have how do you solve this problem, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This would indicate that there isn't a safe upgrade path to your installed app from your instant app. Some of the validations here are

- The instant app permissions should be <= installable app permissions
- The device space for installable should not be more restrictive than the instant app. i.e. .
- Instant app should not have minSdk < installable app mindSdk

In other words, if the device can run instant app, it should be able to run your installable app.

Comment: we have the same problem as OP, my app AndroidManifest is only has single <manifest .... /> tag, are you saying we have to put permission and other required meta data in <manifest ..>....</manifest> ?

Comment: Thanks for replying but  1/ I have 0 permissions in both the installed app and the instant app (it's just a very simple test app for now)   2/ I don't understand what this means ("device space?")  3/ I just checked: the minSdk is 23 everywhere.

Comment: Like Anirudh mentioned, it is because your installed app is more restrictive than your instant app, creating potential instances where a device can install the instant, but not the installed-app. This might help to find that difference: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: But if you can’t solve it on your own, you could file a bug and see if they can assist you. Also, please share link to your bug back in here so it would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787