# Instant app won't start directly, shows a screen first

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have successfully published a (very simple) Instant App linked to my personal website.

When I click on my website's link, I was expecting the app to start directly, but instead, I first see a screen with 2 buttons: "Open app" and "Open in browser":

[image: Screen]

**Why?**

Other instant apps that I tried do not show this screen and open the app directly (the desired behavior).

Comment: I also can see the same behavior on a Nexus 5X API 24 emulator, but when I use other setups (Pixel API 24 and Nexus 5X API 26) instant app starts directly, no "Open in browser” option is present. Try?

Comment: The thing is, on the same device, I have both behaviors, depending on the app.

Comment: Can you check your app with these tests? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#testing App Linking must first work before Instant Apps can.

Comment: @JuliaK It *does* work though - my only problem is that it first shows the above screen. But other than that it works.

Comment: Please try this: 1. Google > Instant Apps > turn "off" (top-right) | 2. Uninstall ⸢Google Play services for Instant Apps⸥ (and if the installed-app is installed, also uninstall) | 3. re-run your instant-app

Comment: Not sure why I would want to do that @TWL, the question has been answered.

Comment: @BoD did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We call this screen the "speed bump". It's a security feature. You're right in noticing that it doesn't always trigger. But there's nothing you, as a developer, can do to control whether it shows. The intention is for it to be a black box from your perspective.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well I wouldn't say it is problematic but since it is not documented and not happening with other apps I tried I thought there was a problem with my code. Therefore I *strongly* suggest you document this behavior in the guides/reference documentation - that will save people from being confused.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @philo I have never seen the speed bump on wish and BuzzFeed. Is there any way you (Google) could remove it from my app? If so could you please post the details.

Comment: my instant app download size is 1.2 MB and I'm still seeing this speed bump. There are no extra permissions. Is there a way to bypass it? Otherwise my purpose on going from mobile web to instant app is useless

Comment: @philo I've reached out to google play support. But they are not even understanding the problem. This is very critical for us. Is there any way we can get over this?

Comment: This happened to my new instant app as well. I noticed https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty (my go-to reference instant app) always opens up directly, while my instant app presents the choice. Good to know there's nothing I can do about it! Maybe after some period of time and because of early concerns with "instant app viruses," Google trusts the instant app enough to open immediately?

Comment: @ScottyB, thanks for sharing about  buzzfeed.com/tasty. I am surprised to know how they're able to bypass speed bump screen if this is not possible to bypass as developer.

Answer (score -1):

This is designed in my opinion to happen at least once to give the user an opportunity to decide what to use: either browser or the instant apps feature.

Comment: Alas, you didn't read the part where I say that it doesn't happen with other apps...

Comment: @BoD could you tell me another instant app, I am curious by myself. Wish for example was exactly like that.

Comment: Well for instance the StackOverflow app   You can click on this to trigger it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858798/instant-app-wont-start-directly-shows-a-screen-first/44953956#

Comment: @Bod sorry, but it opens for me just in a normal browser. How you get this triggered with an instance app?

Comment: You need to have this link somewhere else, not in the browser.  Copy/paste it in a messaging app for instance.

Comment: @BoD still opens a browser from the Gmail application for example.

Comment: It looks like you don't have Instant Apps enabled