# instant app not launching only on first attempt

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

After digging through a myriad of proguard issues, etc, I have the beta pre-release track for my instant app in place and "working" if I click a url link I've emailed myself. The reason I say "working" is because the *first* time I click the link I am taken to the instant app ui (that says 'open app' etc) but oddly the little progress bar does not load. Also, if I click 'open app' I simply am directed back to the email I came from.

BUT... if I then click that link again, the instant app is fully working. I've tried uninstalling the instant app, turning off/on instant apps, etc. The device is a pixel 1.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm seeing no relevant errors in logcat for that first launch besides a few warnings about permissions.

---

Related, but doesn't note the 'first time' problem I have: [Instant app won't start directly, shows a screen first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858798/instant-app-wont-start-directly-shows-a-screen-first)

Comment: Strange. Can you share your package name or the URL you're using? What OS version are you running? Are you able to repro this consistently, and if so, what does it take to reset the state back to "first attempt"? (i.e. is it enough to delete the app from Recent Instant Apps)

Comment: @philo www.rentjungle.com. The instant app is in pre-release fyi. To get back to the first attempt state I'm simply going and deleting the instant app. I have tried turning off/on instant app support too though. Latest 8.x on the pixel (sorry I don't have it on me right now)

Comment: No problem, I can look that up. When you say "delete", you mean through the Instant Apps settings UI? (As opposed to doing something through adb.)

Comment: @philo when I say delete, I mean go into settings->apps where the instant app is listed, and delete it there by selecting it and hitting 'clear app' which removes it

Comment: @shawnall I tested just now on a Pixel XL running 8.0, but I'm not seeing the issues you described. Your app is crashing for me though. Btw, rereading what you originally wrote, I see that you seem to be expecting the progress bar to show before you click Open App. The download doesn't start until after you click that, and the progress bar displays on the loading activity.

Comment: @philo is it consistently crashing? I only see that crash on the first launch then it works fine after that. Also, I get no stack trace in logcat for that initial 'what appears to be a crash'.

Comment: @philo also we made a change to the sandboxVersion or something like that last week and that made that progress bar show up *before* clicking open app. All very weird and inconsistent.

Comment: @shawnwall, Incase the problem is still not solved, I would suggest you to file a bug and see if Google can assist you. Also, please share link to your bug back in here so it would be helpful for all. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787
TIP: Google might need sample project/Instant Application (with this issue) to provide a quick solution.

Comment: I have seem this happen before, but rare. It could simply be a network/latency issue where Play is unable to verify that an instant app exists for it, but once it does, it is saved to your cache.