# Is it possible to open Instant app directly without disambiguation dialog?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have deployed a simple instant app to play store and map a URL to my website using App Link, but when I tried to open instant app from another app for the first time, I always got the disambiguation dialog, letting user confirm whether open instant app or open in browser.

Instant app dialog.

[image: instant app dialog]
but the dialog makes a very bad user experience, is it possible that I can remove it and open my instant app directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant app won't start directly, shows a screen first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858798/instant-app-wont-start-directly-shows-a-screen-first)

Comment: thanks you for the reply, I've noticed the post, but the question doesn't answer when and why "speed bump" will show, actually, this screen blocks user to experience instant app a lot, would you please provide more detail about  "speed bump" if possible? thanks

Comment: Well, the details behind "when and why" are probably not clearly defined or set in stone yet. But since this product is less than 2 years old, it is there so users know they are transitioning to an "app" experience and not to a browser.