# Clicking on app link is not opening instant app directly

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

When I click on app link, it's showing me this screen

[image]

I was expecting the instant app to be opened directly. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858798

Comment: It doesn't fully answer the question. I've already posted a question in the comments over there. There has been no response

Answer (score 1):

**Create App Links for Instant Apps:**

If you've already followed the guides to Create Deep Links to App Content and Verify Android App Links, then you've already done most of the work necessary to make app links work with your instant app. There are just a couple extra rules when using app links for instant apps:

- All intent filters used as app links in your instant app must support
  both HTTP and HTTPS. For example:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
       <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```

For more: Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links).

After that, [Change how you open instant apps from links](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211).

Comment: It supports both http and https. All the points mentioned here are taken care of.

Comment: @ViswanathKumarSandu yes!

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Help [Change how you open instant apps from links](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211) states:

> You can change your settings to open links into instant apps or websites. If you turn on “Upgrade web links,” and click certain links, the instant app may open and you’ll be able to use some of it’s features, without actually installing the full app. If the setting is turned off, the link will open in a website. Learn more about instant apps. *[...]*
>
> Even when this setting is turned off, you can always continue to try instant apps by clicking on links that are Google Play branded. *[...]*

So it seems up to the user how to handle the links.

Comment: If the "Upgrade web links" is disabled, it'll directly open up the browser. If it's enabled, then it is showing this screen. Ideally, this screen shouldn't come