# Non-upgradable to installed app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I change code-base of existing application structure for the instant application.

It looks ok and no issue in pre-release but when I tried rollout in production it saying

> Non-upgradable to installed app
>
> PROBLEM
>
> Some users of this Instant App APKs will not be eligible for any of the APKs in your installed app.
>
> RESOLUTION
>
> Ensure that the targeting of your Instant App APKs matches the targeting of your APKs.

I did not publish installable APK with a new structure.

Is that required to publish installable APK with the new Structure?

Comment: Yes, if you move your instant app to the production stage, then the installed-app counterpart will need to match it.

Comment: This has been answered in detail elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975231/google-play-console-error-non-upgradable-to-installed-app.

Answer (score 0):

Installable apk and instant app have same application structure for both.

There is some inappropriate string for error message, **can you ensure fix with, installable APK in alpha, beta or production with same HOST web '`intent-filter`'.**

Comment: Thank you , i have open question how i can access instant app which i put in pre-release