# Some users of this Instant App APKs will not be eligible for any of the APKs in your installed app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am getting below issue while reviewing the instant app APK for publishing in Google play store.I have minSDKVersion 16 and targetSDKVersion 26 for both instant and installable app.

**PROBLEM**
Some users of this Instant App APKs will not be eligible for any of the APKs in your installed app.
**RESOLUTION**
Ensure that the targeting of your Instant App APKs matches the targeting of your APKs.

Instant app apk is running fine in android studio and i am able to upload it in google play development and pre-release.I have added only necessary permissions for the instant app.Permissions count in instant app is less than installable app. Same default-url is added in instant and installable Android Manifest file.Instant app is also upgradable to installable app.

Thanks in advance.

```
**app_appt1**
package: name='com.xxxxxxxxxxxx' versionCode='151' versionName='5.9.2' platformBuildVersionName=''
install-location:'auto'
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'26'
uses-permission: name='com.xxxxxxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_SMS'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_TASKS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-640:'res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-65534:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.yyyyyy.login.SplashScreen'  label='XXXXXXX' icon=''
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' reason='requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
feature-group: label=''
  uses-gl-es: '0x20000'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.front'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.telephony'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, and requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait' reason='one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales:
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320' '480' '640' '65534'

**base_aapt1**
package: name='com.xxxxxxxx' versionCode='150' versionName='1.0' platformBuildVersionName=''
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'26'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='com.xxxxxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
launchable-activity: name='com.YYYYYYYYY.registration.RegistrationActivity'  label='' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.camera' reason='requested android.permission.CAMERA permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait' reason='one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony' reason='requested a telephony permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
main
other-activities
other-receivers

**registration_aapt1**
package: name='com.xxxxxxxxx' versionCode='150' versionName='1.0' split='registration' platformBuildVersionName=''
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'26'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
application: label='' icon=''
launchable-activity: name='com.yyyyyy.registration.RegistrationActivity'  label='' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.camera' reason='requested android.permission.CAMERA permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait' reason='one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony' reason='requested a telephony permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales:
densities: '160'
```

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Console error - Non-upgradable to installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975231/google-play-console-error-non-upgradable-to-installed-app)