# Instant app release error: targeting apk difference

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

I'm getting this problem when trying to release my instant app in google play console:

```
PROBLEM

Some users of this Instant App APKs will not be eligible for any of the APKs in your installed app.

RESOLUTION

Ensure that the targeting of your Instant App APKs matches the targeting of your APKs.
```

I've searched for the solution and found this question: [Google Play Console error - Non-upgradable to installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975231/google-play-console-error-non-upgradable-to-installed-app).

I've debugged my apks (instant app artifact is .zip archive, so I've extracted it and analyzed apk stored there) with aapt tool and here is the differences I found:

Installed app output:

```
...
application-label-es-ES:’app-name’
...
application-icon-65535:'res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png’
...
 uses-gl-es: '0x20000'
...
```

Instant app doesn't have such lines.
Also there are two locales in installed app, which haven't appear in instant app: `es-ES` and `id`, and one density: `65545`.

All other content (including all permissions) is identical. I don't provide outputs, because they are too large, but if it's necessary, I can attach them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the line `uses-gl-es: '0x20000'`. It says that the application uses OpenGl library. The reason it's used is the dependency on `play-services-maps` library in installed app, but not in instant app. So, I just added this line in instant app dependencies:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0`

and everything began working. Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: You don't have to add that dependency, you can simply add a `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="integer" />` in your instant app's manifest https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element

Comment: On a more general note, all the uses-features must align up between the full-installed and instant app, so that there doesn't arise a situation where the instant app is installable on a device when the installed-app cannot.